# Kivy RecycleView - How to only allow one selection at a time?

Tags: python, kivy

New to Kivy and fairly new to Python.

I have a functional RecycleView, with a list of items, and I can scroll and select items in it.

I wish to only be able to select one item at a time - not multiple items.  So, if I touch/click another item in the list, any previous selected item should be automatically deselected.

I have code that is "almost functional", in that it visually appears to work - the previously selected item visually changes and *looks* unselected - but in fact programmatically does not appear to have updated.

The manifestation of this is: If I click on an item that has been "automatically selected" by my code, it takes two clicks to Select it.  On the first pass, I note that "is_selected" is false.

So if I have two items in a list "A" and "B", and I first select A, then B.  A looks unselected and B looks selected. (desired behaviour). *But* it then takes two clicks to select "A" again.

Relevant code:

```
class PrintJobBoxLayout(RecycleDataViewBehavior, BoxLayout):
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)
    lastItemSelected = None

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        if is_selected:
            if PrintJobBoxLayout.lastItemSelected is not None:
                PrintJobBoxLayout.lastItemSelected.selected=False
                print("We just unselected the previously selected item")
            PrintJobBoxLayout.lastItemSelected=self

        self.selected = is_selected

        if is_selected:
            print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
        else:
            print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not find the exact issue with the code, but did find a much easier solution.

One can just specify the desired behaviour in the .kv file with:

```
RecycleView:
    SelectableRecycleBoxLayour:
        multiselect: False
        touch_multiselect: False
```